# Get active tab ID from Bootstrap and pass it to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have two pages with 3 tabs each. One page for viewing and another for editing.

When I click the tab 2 from view page and press Edit button, I want to be redirected to tab 2 in Edit page. Similarly, for other tabs as well. Tab 1 from view takes me to tab 1 in Edit, and tab 3 from view takes me to tab 3 in Edit.

So what I want to do is, get the active tab from the 3 tabs, fetch the href value, store the href value such that I can use it as php variable (or any other way) in the same page and pass it on to the button link to redirect correctly.

I am using Bootstrap and Codeigniter.

To fetch the href from the active tab; I found this:

```
$('.nav-tabs .active > a').attr('href')
```

This will give me the concerned href name like tab1, tab2, tab3:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
```

I have a line in my PHP code like:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('backend/edit/'. $uid . '<GET THE ACTIVE TAB HREF VALUE HERE>') ?>">Edit</a>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have assigned this $('.nav-tabs .active > a').attr('href') to a variable, but no idea how to proceed beyond this. I am also not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: You dont need it in php, you just need to pass the $uid into the html. I see nothing in the PHP end that requires the active tab to be passed up to the php. Instead pass the uid var down into js and use js to format the link and redirect.

Comment: UID is something else here.

Comment: @trollster doesnt matter what it is, if its a PHP variable, pass it into the page.

Comment: Put it into session with AJAX if u wanna use it later in your PHP code. Otherwise use full javascript solution :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change your link a little bit, like this:

```
<a id="EditLink" href="<?= site_url('backend/edit/'. $uid) ?>">Edit</a>
```

And add this when you click on the tab, where :

```
var tabValue = $(".nav-tabs .active > a").attr("href");
var url = $("#EditLink").attr("href");
$("#EditLink").attr("href", AppendToUrl(url, "tab", tabValue));
```

With the function `AppendToUrl`:

```
function AppendToUrl(url, key, value) {
    var regex = /\?/i;
    if (regex.test(url)) {
        return url + "&" + key + "=" + value;
    } else {
        return url + "?" + key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Active tab is client side, PHP is server side. You can eventually use javascript to send AJAX query:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { active_tab_id: jquery_function_returning_id() }
})
  .done(function( url ) {
    $("#id_of_element_u_want_inject_href").attr("href", url)
  });
```

Some.php:

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo site_url('backend/edit/'. $uid . $data['active_tab_id']);
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable']=$data['active_tab_id'];
?>
```

You should be able to access data in session.

Best would be full javascript solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Handle this in JS by passing the uid down instead of the selected tab up.

Something like this.

```
var uid = <?PHP echo $uid; ?>;
function getHref() {
    var selTab = $('.nav-tabs .active > a').attr('href');
    var retHref = 'backend/edit/' + uid + selTab;
    return retHref
}
```

May need a PHP script to shiv this into site_url() whatever that does, but thats easy enough.

Answer (score -2):

You should achieve this wit javasvript...
When click on a tab get its id and then set required href for any element ...